# I am trying to make a file delete program

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I get winErrors at runtime like 'The system cannot find the file specified', but I know that those files exist... The idea is to try and use recurssion to embed itself into every file, and then delete them, which greatly decreases the time spent deleting the files. My friend made this in Java, and it managed to delete 3GBs in 11 seconds. I wanted to use the same idea with Python and this is the result.

```
import os, sys, glob, fileinput, string
from os import * 

def fileInput():
    #asks for input of a file path
    Folder = input("Please input a file path: ")
    filePathLength = len(Folder)
    #checks to make sure input was provided
    if filePathLength == 0:
        print("Please provide a folder...")
        fileInput()
    else:
    #checks to make sure that it is a proper path, ie- that is has ":\\"
    if Folder.find(":\\") == -1:
        print("Make sure the path is valid")
        fileInput()
    else:
        #if the path is a directory it calls the delete folder function
        print("Inputted path: " + Folder)
        if os.path.isdir(Folder):
            deleteFolder(Folder)
        else:
            print("Path does not exist...")
            fileInput()

def deleteFolder(pathDir):
    print(str(pathDir))
    try:
        for folder in os.listdir(pathDir):
            if folder.find(".") == -1:
                deleteFolder(pathDir + "\\" + folder)
    except NotADirectoryError as notADirectory:
        print(str(notADirectory))
    try:
        for folder in os.listdir(pathDir):
           if folder.find(".") != -1:
                os.remove(folder)
                print("deleted file " + str(folder))
    except IOError as errorCheck:
        print(str(errorCheck))

fileInput()
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated. I am using Python 3.3 on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Never heard of os.walk or the shutil module?

Comment: try `deleteFolder = shutil.rmtree`. Show the full traceback

Comment: use `if a in b` instead of `if b.find(a) != -1`

Comment: I suspect the OP is trying to write his own equivalent to `shutil.rmtree` (and his own `os.walk` along the way) as a learning exercise, not because he actually needs a script that does the exact same thing as the cmd builtin `deltree`.

Comment: You may want to look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/shutil.py#l423) to `rmtree` to see how it's implemented. It's pretty simple—and, if you only care about Windows (and therefore don't need to worry about symlinks, and can't take advantage of the "safe `_use_fd_functions`" stuff), you can make it even simpler. (Or look at [the 3.2 version](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/shutil.py#l243), which didn't have the fd function stuff, so it's more readable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just need:

```
import shutil

path = input("Enter path to delete")

shutil.rmtree(path);
```

Comment: Did you not see his "I am using Python 3.3"? `input()` is exactly what he wants; `raw_input` is a `NameError`.

Comment: @abarnert Oops, my bad - I've changed raw_input to input and remove the note.

Comment: Thanks, looks like os.remove doesn't work in this context, using shutil.rmtree() worked perfectly. Thank you everyone for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

`os.listdir()` returns relative paths. Use full path `os.remove(os.path.join(pathDir, folder))`.